# Конвертировать список чисел в список символов

Tags: c#, массивы

```
List<int> list = new List<int>(){10,202,3};
var rezult = list .Select(x => Convert.ToChar(x)).ToList();
```

в rezult у нас получается

```
10'\n'
202'Ê'
3''
```

Почему туда добавились цифры из массива?) по идее должны были остаться только символы.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Никакие цифры у вас не добавились. Скорее всего вы просто смотрите на результат в режиме отладки, а там действительно отображаются не только символы, но и их коды.

Если же вы, скажем, выведете этот массив на консоль например так:

```
foreach (var ch in rezult)
{
    Console.Write(ch);
}
```

то, разумеется, никаких цифр не увидите